# How to connect a keyPressevent to a lambda?

Tags: c++, windows, qt

Is it possible to connect a `keyPressEvent` or a `mousePressEvent` to a lambda, like you can connect a signal:

```
    connect(ui.treeWidget, &QTreeWidget::currentItemChanged, [=](QTreeWidgetItem* item,  QTreeWidgetItem* previous)
    {
        qDebug() << "item: " << item->text(0);
    });
```

What I tried:

```
    connect(ui.treeWidget, QEvent::Type::KeyPress, [=](QKeyEvent* event)
    {

    });
```

But I got this error:

`no instance of overloaded function "MainWindow::connect" matches the argument list`

To handle these events the unique option is subclassing the widget?

Comment: Do you know how to do it without a lambda?

Comment: @ThomasWeller only by subclassing the widget and listening directly `void keyPressEvent(QKeyEvent* event) { ... }`

Comment: A signal is not thrown for an event.

Comment: @drescherjm the signal was just an example, so the connection using lambda only works for signals?

Comment: `connect()` works with signals and slots and not events.

Comment: You could use an event filter it you don'r want to subclass your widget: [https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/eventsandfilters.html#event-filters](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/eventsandfilters.html#event-filters)

Comment: @drescherjm I'm trying to improve the performance of my UI, an event filter is less costly than subclassing the widget?

Comment: Probably more costly although for key press events it won't matter because performance is limited to the users typing speed and very much not the CPU.